# Filling missing values from other rows in group (including duplicates)

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has some missing values which I want to fill with other members of the same group. However, in some cases there is more than one value for each group and in these cases I want all the rows in each group to be replicated to have one row containing each value.

Sample data:

```
   ID group value
1   1     A  blue
2   2     A  <NA>
3   3     A  <NA>
4   4     B green
5   4     B   red
6   5     B  <NA>
7   6     B  <NA>
8   7     C  blue
9   8     C green
10  9     C    NA
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
  ID group value
1  1     A  blue
2  2     A  blue
3  3     A  blue
4  4     B green
5  4     B   red
6  5     B green
7  5     B   red
8  6     B green
9  6     B   red
10 7     C  blue
11 7     C green
12 8     C  blue
13 8     C green
14 9     C  blue
15 9     C green
```

I have some cases where the group contains one ID which has two values (like group B) and others were there is more than one ID in the group, each with a different value (like C). In any case, I want a table where each member of the group has every value present in that group. I've found some answers dealing with simple cases like group A but none that have more than one value per group.

==== EDIT ====

My actual dataset is much bigger which has caused some additional problems. An updated sample table is below:

```
ID group value specific_value dataversion
1     A  blue       sky_blue    version1
2     A  <NA>           <NA>    version2
3     A  <NA>           <NA>    version1
4     B green   forest_green    version1
4     B   red        scarlet    version1
5     B  <NA>           <NA>    version2
6     B  <NA>           <NA>        <NA>
7     C  blue     royal_blue    version2
8     C green     lime_green    version1
9     C  <NA>           <NA>    version1
```

For each group I want to have a row with each set of value + specific_value from that group (but I wouldn't want a row with eg. blue and lime_green) for each member of the group. I want all the values for the other columns (ID, group, and dataversion) to be left as-is (including if eg. dataversion is NA).

Expected output:

```
ID group value specific_value dataversion
1     A  blue       sky_blue    version1
2     A  blue       sky_blue    version2
3     A  blue       sky_blue    version1
4     B green   forest_green    version1
4     B   red        scarlet    version1
5     B green   forest_green    version2
5     B   red        scarlet    version2
6     B green   forest_green        <NA>
6     B   red        scarlet        <NA>
7     C  blue     royal_blue    version2
7     C green     lime_green    version2
8     C  blue     royal_blue    version1
8     C green     lime_green    version1
9     C  blue     royal_blue    version1
9     C green     lime_green    version1
```

Ie. each combination of ID, group, and dataversion in the table is the same as the original table but there is now a row for each combination of value and specific_value for each group. Note in my actual table I have ~50 columns of data (1 grouping column, ~6 are the equivalent to value/specific value here and the rest are treated like ID/dataversion) so I'd prefer not to have to type every column name.

Comment: What would be the expected output for this new data

Comment: Have updated the post @akrun

Comment: Do you also need combination for `specifc_value` column

Comment: @akrun Yes. It's possible in my dataset I could have an individual who has "green" in the `value` column twice with both "forest_green" and "lime_green" in `specific_value`. But the entry in `specific_value` should always be with it's respective `value` entry (not green with sky_blue etc).

Comment: @stiba try `df2 %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(valnew =  str_c(value, specific_value, sep=":")) %>% select(-value, -specific_value) %>% complete(ID, valnew = unique(valnew[!is.na(valnew)])) %>% filter(!is.na(valnew)) %>% separate(valnew, into = c('value', 'specific_value'), sep=":") %>% fill(dataversion)`

Comment: @akrun That doesn't seem to be treating `dataversion` correctly. It's giving each row the `dataversion` from the row where `value` and `specific_value` are copied from. Ie. `ID=2` swaps from `version2` to `version1` the same as `ID=1`

Comment: Can you check the updated code

Comment: @akrun I need each ID number to still have the same dataversion as in the initial table but after the `complete()` stage the `dataversion` column is set to NA for any row which didn't have `value` & `specific_value` set in the initial table. `fill()` is then re-adding values to the column but these don't match what was there to start

Comment: Please check the updated one in my post.  I did update after the last comment

Comment: I crosschecked with your expected and couldn't find any difference

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that updated version seems to work. I didn't see your comment until I had posted mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need `complete` here.  After grouping by 'group', use `complete` to get the combinations of `unique` non-NA 'value' for each 'group' and 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   complete(ID, value = unique(value[!is.na(value)])) %>%
   na.omit %>%
   select(names(df1))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#      ID group value
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 A     blue 
# 2     2 A     blue 
# 3     3 A     blue 
# 4     4 B     green
# 5     4 B     red  
# 6     5 B     green
# 7     5 B     red  
# 8     6 B     green
# 9     6 B     red  
#10     7 C     blue 
#11     7 C     green
#12     8 C     blue 
#13     8 C     green
#14     9 C     blue 
#15     9 C     green
```

#### Update

with the new dataset, we can do

```
df2 %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(valnew = str_c(value, specific_value, sep=":")) %>% 
   select(-value, -specific_value, -dataversion) %>%
   complete(ID, valnew = unique(valnew[!is.na(valnew)])) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(valnew)) %>% 
   separate(valnew, into = c('value', 'specific_value'), sep=":") %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   left_join(df2 %>% 
               select(ID, dataversion)) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(rn)) %>%
   select(names(df2))
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
#      ID group value specific_value dataversion
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>      
# 1     1 A     blue  sky_blue       version1   
# 2     2 A     blue  sky_blue       version2   
# 3     3 A     blue  sky_blue       version1   
# 4     4 B     green forest_green   version1   
# 5     4 B     red   scarlet        version1   
# 6     5 B     green forest_green   version2   
# 7     5 B     red   scarlet        version2   
# 8     6 B     green forest_green   <NA>       
# 9     6 B     red   scarlet        <NA>       
#10     7 C     blue  royal_blue     version2   
#11     7 C     green lime_green     version2   
#12     8 C     blue  royal_blue     version1   
#13     8 C     green lime_green     version1   
#14     9 C     blue  royal_blue     version1   
#15     9 C     green lime_green     version1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
    group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
    ), value = c("blue", NA, NA, "green", "red", NA, NA, "blue", 
    "green", NA)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")


df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
    group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
    ), value = c("blue", NA, NA, "green", "red", NA, NA, "blue", 
    "green", NA), specific_value = c("sky_blue", NA, NA, "forest_green", 
    "scarlet", NA, NA, "royal_blue", "lime_green", NA), dataversion = c("version1", 
    "version2", "version1", "version1", "version1", "version2", 
    NA, "version2", "version1", "version1")), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!

For any future readers, I had some issues first because my group and value columns were set as factors instead of characters but when I fixed that it all worked

Comment: @stlba  If you have more columns, thene what do you want to fill in those columns beecause obviously, the values are not in those columns for the required combinations

Comment: Sorry, accidently pressed enter before I had finished typing.

I've run into a problem. My actual data has more columns than the 3 mentioned here which are all being converted to NA after the complete step. In reality, I have one group of columns which already have values which I want to be duplicated into all the new rows (ie. treated like ID here - there are a lot of these so I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve me typing every column name), and a second group which I want to be treated like value here (these columns are related so all rows either have a value in all of them or none)

Comment: I think using complete(nesting()) is the answer but I can't quite figure out how to get it to work

Comment: @stlba  If you want the values to be duuplicated, then use `%>% fill`

Comment: @stlba  You can either specify the colums of interest as `%>%fill(colname1, colname2, othercol)` or use a tidyhelper `%>% fill(matches('colname"))`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained myself well. I've added another example to the main post.