# How to combine missing values from other duplicated row, return a more complete data and remove the duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, missing-data

Here's my dataframe:

```
df1 = structure(list(item = c("HY04SB", "HY04SB", "GSP8Y1", "GSP8Y1", 
"9PLM0A", "9PLM0A"), weird = c("w'`tc7>", NA, NA, "($^-yk1%", 
"jd(,*'7_", NA), simple = c(NA, 14661746, 58489634, NA, NA, NA
), code = c("WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3", "WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3", "$8@g44;T7w'{8e^=", 
NA, NA, "(X<f..\\Js9da]CE")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  item   weird      simple code              
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>             
1 HY04SB w'`tc7>        NA "WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3"
2 HY04SB NA       14661746 "WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3"
3 GSP8Y1 NA       58489634 "$8@g44;T7w'{8e^="
4 GSP8Y1 ($^-yk1%       NA  NA               
5 9PLM0A jd(,*'7_       NA  NA               
6 9PLM0A NA             NA "(X<f..\\Js9da]CE"
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
structure(list(item = c("HY04SB", "GSP8Y1", "9PLM0A"), weird = c("w'`tc7>", 
"($^-yk1%", "jd(,*'7_"), simple = c(14661746, 58489634, NA), 
    code = c("WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3", "$8@g44;T7w'{8e^=", "(X<f..\\Js9da]CE"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  item   weird      simple code              
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>             
1 HY04SB w'`tc7>  14661746 "WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3"
2 GSP8Y1 ($^-yk1% 58489634 "$8@g44;T7w'{8e^="
3 9PLM0A jd(,*'7_     NA   "(X<f..\\Js9da]CE"
```

I tried the solution from [Filling missing values from other rows in group (including duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614306/filling-missing-values-from-other-rows-in-group-including-duplicates) but without any success and don't think it's what I want because it's not in the reduced dataframe with incomplete variables removed, and not sure how to retain one of the row with NA as it's more complete than previous duplicates...

```
new_df <- df1 %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  mutate(valnew = str_c(weird, simple, code, sep=":")) %>% 
  select(-weird, -simple, -code) %>%
  complete(ID, valnew = unique(valnew[!is.na(valnew)])) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(valnew)) %>% 
  separate(valnew, into = c('weird', 'simple', 'code'), sep=":") %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% 
              select(ID)) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(rn)) %>%
  select(names(df1))
```

Can someone assist this, how to produce the result in 3 x 4 as shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fil1` after grouping to give rows that share the same item the same information and then `slice` to select n amount of observations per group

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 |> 
  group_by(item) |> 
  fill(-item, .direction = "updown") |> 
  slice(1) |> 
  ungroup()
```

```
  item   weird      simple code              
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>             
1 9PLM0A jd(,*'7_       NA "(X<f..\\Js9da]CE"
2 GSP8Y1 ($^-yk1% 58489634 "$8@g44;T7w'{8e^="
3 HY04SB w'`tc7>  14661746 "WX&}Awx:65Dgn9A3"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with sapply

```
  df1 = as_tibble(t(
  sapply(unique(df1$item), function(X) # "loop" over  items
  sapply(colnames(df1), function(COL)  # get unique value of each column else give NA
  ifelse(length((REF = unique(df1[df1$item == X, COL][!is.na(df1[df1$item == X, COL])]))), REF, NA)))
  ))

df1<-readr::type_convert(df1) #auto change column type.
```